# React-Native: Async Storage no such table

Tags: android, asynchronous, storage, react-native

At the opening of my app I'm trying to get some preferences via `AsyncStorage.multiGet` or `AsyncStorage.getItem`. Unfortunately the very first time I open the app, the SQLite table used by AsyncStorage in Android, doesn't exist. And so the app crashes. How should I handle the error to avoid having a red death screen.

FYI the exception thrown is :

```
no such table: catalystLocalStorage (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO catalystLocalStorage VALUES (?, ?);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the version of `react-native`, provide sample code etc ?

Comment: I restarted my project and rewrote my code, the error wasn't thrown anymore ... I don't really know what happened. Thanks for your concern anyway

Comment: @ilansas if you want to take a little boilerplate out of your AsyncStorage interaction I wrote a little library to simplify saving and fetching data called [react-native-simple-store](npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-store).